# Adding/Remove 1 Hour from a line that references date (PHP)

Tags: php, magento2.2.7

I'm attempting to debug a Timezone issue in a custom Magento module. One of the tests I would like to try is to ADD/REMOVE 1hr from whatever is output from this line of code.

I suspect ADDING 1hr could be as simple as implementing a "+1" somehow. And perhaps REMOVING 1hr might involve going back 1 Day and forward 23 hours. But honestly, I don't know what to start with this.

**Line**

```
$estimatedDeliveryDate = $this->localeDate->date()->setTime(0,0,0);
```

**Context**

```
class Estimator
{
    private $localeDate;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
    ) {
        $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
    }

    public function addEstimatedDeliveryDate(&$items)
    {
        $now = $this->localeDate->date();
        $todayDate = $this->localeDate->date();

         foreach ($items as &$item) {
            $estimatedDeliveryDate = $this->localeDate->date()->setTime(0,0,0);

...
```

Comment: this `setTime(Hours,Minutes,Seconds);` , what do you want to do?

Comment: With Daylight Savings on Sunday, my Delivery Date selector seems to break when trying to choose a date during that period of time. It appears the code was never written to take Daylight into account. So, to test and debug I wanted to see what would happen if I adjusted the code +/- 1hr to see what effect that would have.

Comment: `setTime(Hours,Minutes,Seconds);` might work for +1 but not -1.

Comment: since it is for testing purpose only, you can try like this `$estimatedDeliveryDate = $this->localeDate->date('2019-03-30')->setTime(0,0,0)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');`

Comment: when you -1 day just change to `$estimatedDeliveryDate = $this->localeDate->date('2019-03-29')->setTime(0,0,0)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');`

Comment: Gotcha. I'll try that out in a bit, cheers

Comment: yeah, and also you can use date only since time doesn't matter as you are checking days, like `$estimatedDeliveryDate = $this->localeDate->date('2019-03-29')->format('Y-m-d');` then in +1 `$estimatedDeliveryDate = $this->localeDate->date('2019-03-30')->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: did it resolve the issue? can I post it as answer? Thanks

Comment: It didn't give me the expected results. Not sure if that was the solution of whether I was editing the wrong code to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of code below, I' able to add number of days/hours to current date and time.

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $_timezoneInterface;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param TimezoneInterface $timezoneInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TimezoneInterface $timezoneInterface
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_timezoneInterface = $timezoneInterface;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrderScheduledAt(): string
    {
        $x = '2'; // Number of days to be added (same way you can use 'hours')
        $currentDateTime = $this->_timezoneInterface->date()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
        return $this->_timezoneInterface->date(strtotime($currentDateTime." +{$x} days"))->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    }

}
```

In the same way, you can use `$this->_timezoneInterface->date(strtotime($currentDateTime." +1 days"))->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');`  to add one hour.